# “As armas e os barões assinalados” - que barões são estes?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto, literatura, história

Estava a ler *Os Lusíadas* de Luís Vaz de Camões e já não me lembro da análise da 1ª estrofe do Canto I.

> Canto I
>
> As armas e os barões assinalados,

Tentei procurar um comentário crítico na internet, mas sem sucesso. São muitos os comentários gerais que não entram em grande profundidade. Também não encontrei uma análise crítica, de referência, com a autoridade que se deseja para uma obra destas.

Portanto, eis a pergunta: quais são os significados da palavra *"barões"* nesta estrofe?

Comment: Cf. ***“Arma virumque** cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris”* de Virgílio. :)

Comment: Nas Cantigas de Santa Maria (~1200), um barão ou varão são um homem, sendo, se eu bem me lembro, “home(m)” mais usado com outro significado. Hodiernamente “varão” é ou uma vara grande ou homem, e “barão” é ou um homem de poder ou um homem.  Interessante que, de acordo Houaiss, tanto “varão” quanto “barão” quando no sentido de “homem”, têm uma conotação de homem valeroso, forte, corajoso, bravo, etc. Não tenho ciência de qual acepção Camões usou, mas quando estava lendo Os Lusíadas, interpretei “barão” como equivalente a “homem”. Agora sabendo da conotação, ME faria ainda mais sentido essa.

Comment: @tchrist já me tinha esquecido de Vrigílio, obrigado por recordares.

Comment: @Schilive pois, sei. Sigo em linha com o teu óptimo comentário, mas faltam umas obras de referência que possamos consultar na net.

Comment: Este site diz o mesmo http://www.alvarenga.net/canto1.htm. Bad_coder, como poesias têm o descobrimento de seu significado como a tarefa e parte da diversão do autor, não sei se há uma referência forte para isso e mesmo se houver, pessoalmente acho que perde a graça. Já ouvi de alguns amantes de leitura de poesia que não vais entender completamente na primeira vez nem na primeira leitura da poesia, que podes ficar tempos para entender uma linha, estrofe ou canto — mas que está tudo bem deixar aquela parte para a segunda leitura — e que o descobrimento é tua tarefa e diversão

Answer (score 1):

Sim! "Barões assinalados" faz referência à nobreza de homens muito importantes. (aristocrata no sentido de escol da espécie humana). Perceba que: Camões repete Eneida, essa repete, um tantinho, a Ira de Aquiles da Ilíade - quase uma fórmula, aliás , uma delícia.

Comment: Bem vindo ao site pt.se. Obrigado pela resposta, é hábito no site pedirmos que sejam incluidas referências para obras que dêem suporte às respostas.